# Can I drive an LM334(Z) from an Arduino with AnalogWrite()?

Tags: pwm, current

I need programmable current control, fading from zero to 2 milliAmps.  I was hoping to use Arduino's AnalogWrite(), which uses Phase Width Modulation (PWM) to simulate analog output with a sawtooth wave on a duty-cycle; to control an LM334Z to deliver a slowly ramped low current delivery.
[The application is a TransCranial Direct Current Stimulation (TDCS) micro-current delivery to the human scalp. Jumping straight to 2 milliAmps is uncomfortable].
Will PWM work? Or, do I need some sort of smoothing circuitry to soften the PMW before it is applied to the LM334Z's Rset pin to accomplish the above?

Comment: an LED glued to the face of an LDR converts voltage to resistance, but a digital pot would be simpler to calibrate. I'm using a MCP41010 with the 334, which works very well and cost me ~$1us

Comment: an LM317 can provide 0-2ma CC with common 1/4watt resistors, look at the datasheet.

Comment: On Arduino, PWM stands for Pulse Width Modulation, *not*  “Phase Width Modulation”

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need super high accuracy, using a MOSFET's ohmic region, plus a smoothing filter on the output of your PWM (analog out), could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You control the LM334 with a resistance, not a voltage. The current is set by multiplying the current through the resistor.

Maybe you can do what you want by replacing the `Rset` with a digital potentiometer?

Answer (score 0):

> LM334Z's Rset pin to accomplish the above?

Most of that type of circuit has its operations be determined by the current In or out of that pin. So a voltage signal may not work - you will need to experiment. I have had some success with analogs dds chips and linear programmable osscillators.

So try it on your chip. Nothin to lose.

Comment: since it's output current is independent of any voltage, that will not work, it needs a resistor.